# ASP.net MVC3 speed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc-3

I've starting to develop a small web app (by now only for fun, and for learning MVC) using Ruby on Rails and ASP.net MVC3, for learning some background on both systems.

One of the things that I've noticed is that ASP.net is dramatically slower than Ruby (using the default development platforms, Ruby on Mac and MVC3 on Windows/VS2010). I also tried to upload my solution to Azure and test it, but It keeps been slow.

Have you noticed this difference, and how can I improve the performance of my app?

Comment: This site is [using MVC3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network/10370#10370). So you can use for a while to see if it's slow.

Comment: There are too many variables in your test. You're using different operating systems, probably using different dbs, ...

Comment: ... and possibly different hardware...

Comment: I have been using MVC from last 1 and half year...I havenever found my application slow..there must be some different parameters that are causing your application slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to improve the performance of your ASP.Net MVC3 app you need to find out why it is not performing as expected.

You can utilise tools such as the [mvc-mini-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) from the StackOverflow team for server-side performance issues or tools such as [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) or [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) to profile any client side issues.

That said, ROR and ASP.Net MVC3 should, for a non-complex application, broadly perform the same.

Answer (score 1):

What performance are you speaking about? Performance of IDE during development or performance of the application running in a debug mode or performance of the application published on a server?

MVC 3 is not slow, and if you are a learning developer I don't think the performance of MVC or performance in general is something that you need to be concerned with at this stage. Performance is important and it should be in the back of your mind at all times, but there is no need to worry if you are learning a technology. You will eventually hit a bottleneck with performance and you will have to refactor your code to fix it. Just be aware of it and be prepared to face challenges when needed.